# Making left and right sides of page responsive without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've made one webpage which now I'm trying to make responsive. It's very simple page containing signup form and some links left+right side.

The structure is pretty straightforward, like:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="main-content">    
     <div class="text-intro">
        .. some text
     </div>  

     <div id="left-sidebar">            
         <div id="navigation">
              .. some links
         </div>  
     </div>

     <div id="content">
         <div id="form"> 
          .. the form on the right side
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to add media query from some tutorials but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why and how to do this. This is the query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            #wrapper, #main-content, #content, #form{       
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
            }       

}
```

This is the full demo of the above source: https://jsfiddle.net/q97odta6/

Can anyone help a bit here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check viewport **meta** tag added in **head**  tag. If not add following in **head** tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this in my head already `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>`

Comment: remove `margin-left property` for id content in media queries. If that is not correct let me know

Comment: I understand you problem. Even if you set `float` property `margin` property took pixels from screen

Comment: There has to be some option to accomplish this even with this margin, or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
  margin: 0 auto; /* horizontally centered */
}

section {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
}

aside {
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining width */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally centers the content */
  background: lightgreen;
}

article {
  width: 400px; /* fixed width */
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  section {flex-direction: column} /* stacks flex-items vertically */
  article {width: initial} /* back to default behavior */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <section> 
    <aside>            
      <nav>
        links
      </nav>
    </aside>    
    <article>
      text
    </article>
    <aside>
      <form> 
        form
      </form>
    </aside>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.qt4 {
  transition: .4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

* {
  font-family: "Myriad Set Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
  font: 10;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: ;
}

.box {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: white;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.26);
}

.me.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.side_containers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  left: 0px;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.name {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  padding-top: 150px;
  color: black;
  opacity: .15;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .side_containers {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .side_containers .name {
    padding-top: 120px;
  }
  .sides {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .side_containers {
    height: auto;
  }
  .sides {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="qt container">

    <div class="qt center">
      <div class="me box">

        <div class="qt name">Center</div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="qt side_containers">
      <div class="qt sides right">
        <div class="right box">

          <div class="qt name">Right</div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="qt sides left">
        <div class="left box">

          <div class="qt name">Left</div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This is looks good except the center div should be above both ( left and right ) on desktops. Let me try to implement this in my code

Comment: Why is so complicated.. I tough that I just need to select in media query both sides and make them float left. Sorry but it seems that I can't implement this in my current view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something much shorter. This uses the flex box system.
Using float left is not advised in modern design due to the lack of full control over the viewport.

Float Left = Old Design

Flexbox = Modern Design

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: "Myriad Set Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02em;}

.r {position: relative;}

.white {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);}

.container {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;}

.box div {
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}







.side {width: 200px;height: 400px;}
.left.side {margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;}
.right.side {margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;}

.center {
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;}







@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {flex-flow: wrap;}
  .side {width: calc(50% - 10px);}
  .left.side {margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;}
  .right.side {margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;}
  .center {
    width: 100%;
    order: -1;
    margin: 0px;}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {flex-flow: wrap;}
  .side {width: 100%;}
  .left.side {margin: 20px 0 0 0;}
  .right.side {margin: 20px 0 0 0;}}
```

```html
<title>Resize</title>


<body class="">
  <div class="r container">
    <div class="r white box left side">
      <div>Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="r white box center">
      <div>Center</div>
    </div>
    <div class="r white box right side">
      <div>Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```